# What is this error and How to solve it Missing argument 2 for PLATFORMS::get_device_info()

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having this error on my wp multi site ,

```
Warning: Missing argument 2 for PLATFORMS::get_device_info(), called in /homepages/13/d133448570/htdocs/sogolearn/prosper/tracking202/redirect/rtr.php on line 395 and defined in /homepages/13/d133448570/htdocs/sogolearn/prosper/202-config/connect2.php on line 258

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /homepages/13/d133448570/htdocs/sogolearn/prosper/202-config/connect2.php:258) in /homepages/13/d133448570/htdocs/sogolearn/prosper/tracking202/redirect/rtr.php on line 286
```

Page url = http://prosper.sogolearn.com/tracking202/redirect/rtr.php?t202id=8368&t202kw=

Rest of the functions are working properly, no errors on the main site or other domains.
I have no idea what is this error and How to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error is caused by only providing one argument to a function or method that requires at least two arguments. For example, if we have a function like this:

```
function hasTwoArguments($first, $second) {
    // Do something...
}
```

...then the error occurs if it is called like this:

```
// The second argument is required, but is not provided, causing an error
hasTwoArguments('first');
```

The second error is most likely a side-effect of the first error. HTTP headers must be set before any output is sent to the client (the *browser* in this case). The first error outputs a message (describing what went wrong), which is why the second error occurred.

To fix these errors you have to make sure that the `PLATFORMS::get_device_info()` method gets two arguments. If you have written the code yourself then you can either provide the second argument, or you can make the second argument optional (if it indeed *is* optional). If you did not write the code yourself then you should contact the author(s) of the code, telling them that they may have made a mistake.

Comment: Thanks alot, It helped me figure out the issue , I had mistakenly added extra info, I used 
function get_device_info($db, $detect, $ua_string=''){

after editing it to
function get_device_info($db){ problem was fixed.
Thanks a lot